# Why can't I obtain OBJECT_NAME() for a temporary table?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, temporary-tables

According to this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx

> When a temporary table name is specified, the database name must come before the temporary table name, unless the current database is tempdb. For example: `SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytemptable')`.

But when I am actually creating a temp table in a database other than `tempdb` the function is not working as specified:

```
use beta1
create table #t(id int)
select object_name(object_id('tempdb..#t')) as from_beta1
use tempdb
select object_name(object_id('tempdb..#t')) as from_tempdb
drop table #t
```

This is what I see:

```
from_beta1
----------
NULL

from_tempdb
---------------
#t_________________...______0000000000B9
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: So people might actually offer advice about the problem you're trying to solve, could you explain the problem you're trying to solve? What exactly do you plan to do with the long name derived from `OBJECT_NAME()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell `object_name` that it needs to look in the metadata of tempdb.

```
select object_name(object_id('tempdb..#t'), db_id('tempdb')) as from_beta1
```

Comment: `db_id('tempdb')` is always `2` AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

`object_id()` is returning a value fine; the problem is that `object_name()` (which is not the documentation you're looking at) by default looks in `sys.objects` for the current database context.

Don't know why you would need to use `object_name()` here when you obviously already know the name (`#t`). Or are you trying to get `#t___________acde4521`? What exactly are you going to do with `#t___________acde4521`? Why?

You can get it, but I recommend this way instead:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM tempdb.sys.objects 
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#t');
```

Here's why I try to use metadata functions sparingly:

- [Bad habits : Using (certain) metadata "helper" functions](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-metadata-helper-functions)

Still confused about what you're going to do with that name, though...